# How to use formula to transform text to integer?

Tags: formula

I want to use a dropdown list for attributing values to a field. However, for the end user, I want to show easy labes instead of numbers.

I wonder how I can set up a formula to transform that text to integers.

The labels would be: `easy`, `medium` and `hard`. They should be mapped to `0.5`, `1` and `1.5`.

I need to transform those to compute them in another formula.

Here is what it would look like in a basic Python function:

```
def mapping(x):
    y = 1
    if x == 'easy':
         y = 0.5
    elif x == 'medium':
         y = 1
    else:
         y = 1.5
```

**How can I solve this using formulas in Salesforce?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you wanted the user to choose from text values in the picklist, you could do a conversion to numeric factor in the formula itself, using the CASE function.

Suppose you have the three picklist values 'Easy', 'Medium', 'Hard' then you could rewrite your formula field as

```
amount__c * CASE(Boost_Factor__c, 'Easy', 0.5, 'Medium', 1, 'Hard', 1.5, 1)   //final argument is the default if no match
```